# Open a local application from a web browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, azure-devops

I have used Visual Studio online. If you are familiar with it, you know that you can hit the "Open in Visual Studio" link. This will prompt the user that it will open an external application. This is the exact functionality I want. I looked at the resulting link and it is empty as far a HTML/Javascript is concerned. I know that Visual Studio is handling this call, but how is the backend telling the browser this is what it wants to do.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install the application, it sets up an *handler* in the *Windows Registry* linking to a custom URI Scheme that allows the system to know that a specific URI scheme will open a specific window application.

To register your own scheme please refer to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx). 
This [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/10/19/register-a-custom-url-protocol-handler.aspx) also provides a good read on the subject.

This is the same as mobile phones do when you use `mailto:` and `tel:` in a link as they already have internally an handler for those URI Schemes...

Comment: Thank you! I just found another [article](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/86754-How-to-launch-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-rock-instead-of-http) that helped as well